# How to create noise with time dependent correlation in Julia?

Tags: julia, noise

I want to create real noise $\xi(t)$ which fulfills the property $E[xi_t\xi_s] = f(t, s)$ in Julia. Is there a library or function with which I could implement this?
I tried the impementation with $f(t, s) = e^{-(t-s)}$
My code is not working (the noise is decreasing exponentially).

```
using LinearAlgebra

function generate_gaussian_noise(timesteps)
    n = length(timesteps)
    noise = zeros(n)

    for i in 1:n
        t = timesteps[i]
        noise[i] = real(randn())
    end

    return noise
end

function construct_correlated_noise(timesteps)
    n = length(timesteps)
    noise = generate_gaussian_noise(timesteps)
    correlation_matrix = zeros(n, n)

    for i in 1:n
        for j in 1:n
            correlation_matrix[i, j] = exp(-(timesteps[i] - timesteps[j]))
        end
    end

    # Perform eigenvalue decomposition
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = eigen(correlation_matrix)
    D = Diagonal(sqrt.(eigenvalues))
    Q = eigenvectors
    L = Q * D

    correlated_noise = L * noise

    return correlated_noise
end

# Example usage
timesteps = collect(1:401)
correlated_noise = construct_correlated_noise(timesteps)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like this?

```
using Distributions
f(t, s) = exp(-abs(t-s))
timesteps = 1:401;
covariance_matrix = f.(timesteps, timesteps');
mean_vector = zeros(length(timesteps));
d = MvNormal(mean_vector, covariance_matrix);
x = rand(d) # this is a single sample
```

Note that `f(t,s)` must have a property that `f(t,s)=f(s,t)` which your function did not have, that is why I have added `abs`. I also modelled covariance because what you defined is not correlation but covariance assuming that the expected value of the process is constant and equal to 0.

Comment: Oops, posted the same answer about 10 seconds after you :-)

Comment: Is there a simple way to adjust the code for complex noise with given covariance and pseudo-covariance?

Comment: just change the `covariance_matrix` definition.

Comment: I think `covariance_matrix` has to be real-valued and `MvNormal` has no argument for the `pseudo_covariance_matrix`. I thought that perhaps a complex noise can be constructed of 2 `MvNormal` distributions (but then I don't know how to take the pseudo covariance into account)

Comment: I am not aware a package that allows to do it directly (but I might be wrong here). Probably you would need to do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're just asking how to simulate a zero-mean Gaussian vector with arbitrary correlation structure. You can just use the Distributions.jl package to do this. For example:

```
using Distributions
numobs = 100;
muvec = zeros(Float64, numobs);
covmat = Matrix{Float64}(I, numobs, numobs);
x = rand(MvNormal(muvec, covmat);
```

You will, of course, need to populate the `covmat` line with whatever covariance matrix structure you are after. I've just used code for a diagonal covariance matrix here, but you can do whatever you want.

If you have a more specific correlation structure in mind, e.g. maybe an autoregressive structure, then there will be more efficient ways to go about this. But for an arbitrary structure, this is *probably* the best and easiest approach.